# Reactjs Typescript form input elements value not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am new to React and doing a multi step contact form. I have made a handleChange function where i get value of the input, so when i go previous or next, content of the input is shown so you can edit it. First input works great, but i get problem when i put `value={text}` in the second input, when i click next it's stucks on the first input. Please help.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {useStep} from "react-hooks-helper";


const Contact: React.FC = () => {

    const [text, setText] = useState("")
    const {index, navigation: {previous, next},} = useStep({steps: 4});

    function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        const {value} = e.target
        setText(value)
    }

    return (
        <div className="contact">
            <div className="contact-inner">
                <form>
                    {index === 0 && <label>
                        <input onChange={handleChange} value={text}  type="text" name="name"
                               placeholder={"Please enter your name"}/>
                    </label>}
                    {index === 1 && <label htmlFor="email">
                        <input  type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email"/>
                    </label>}
                    {index === 2 && <label>
                        <input  type="text" name="title"
                               placeholder="Please enter the title"/>
                    </label>}
                    {index === 3 && <label>
                        <textarea className="content" name="content" placeholder="Please enter your message"/>
                    </label>}


                </form>
                <div className="buttons">
                    <button className="previous" onClick={previous}>previous</button>
                    <button className="next" onClick={next}>{index === 3 ? 'Submit' : 'Next'}</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Contact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you only have one text state, you should probably create a state for each of your inputs:

```
const [contact, setContact] = useState({
  name: "",
  email: "",
  title: ""
});
```

Then you can display the correct value for each input:

```
<input name='email' value={contact.email} ...
```

And update your handleChange function:

```
function handleChange(event) {
  const {name, value} = event.target;
  setContact({ ...contact, [name]: value });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
on the first state in setContact i get:" Parameter 'state' implicitly has an 'any' type."
in the curly braces i get: "Expected 1 arguments, but got 4 or more."

Comment: Try this: setContact({ ...contact, [name]: value });

Comment: can you please help me.. i need onChange event and value in textarea, same as in input but i get error...

Comment: textarea works exactly the same way. Add a new content to your contact state (content: "")